# Translate QT application without text in code

Tags: qt, translation

Is there a way to translate a QT app into different languages without defining the texts directly in the source? I want to separate the text from source. This would result in some kind of resource files for ALL languages, including the default language (e.g. English).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we will do is:
* Include a translation for the former default language. Using this *.ts file to auto-generate the other *.ts files. This is required as we keep the translations outside the QT environment as they match with other projects not related to QT.

Then have only have to make sure this translation contains the correct value.

In the future we can define IDs in the code witch represent Text in the default translation. Like translating TXT_ID_ABOUT to "About".

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to leave the English (or your source language, not necessarily English) source out of the XML (.ts) files as lupdate will put it there each time you run it.  However as long as a translation exists for the chosen language, the source text will be ignored.  If there is no translation text, it will default to the source text.  This is useful since you'll be guaranteed to get some sort of text in your translation, but it'll be up to your test team to insure that the translations exist.  I wrote a python script to automate the checking of the translation files since we have 9 languages and nearly 1k strings per translation.  To test for this, we used a very simple sed script to create pseudo-loc source strings so if there were translations missing, the pseudo-loc text would be very evident.

Regarding the process for editing the .ts files, we farmed out the translations to individual translators, providing them with the .ts file for their language, and usually about an hour's worth of hand's on instruction in using QT Linguist.  If the translator was onsite and wanted to see their translations on our device immediately, I wrote an autorun script that would place the resultant .qm file in the right place in our embedded file system and restart the application to display the new translations.  If they weren't onsite, we'd run them through the python script mentioned above to check for a number of different problems, then simply check in the .ts file so it'd get built the next time around.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the `QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP` family of macros to do what you want. Those simply mark some text as "need to be translated" so that `lupdate` picks it up, but you can refer to those translated values by variable constants in your code. So ...

```
const char *kHelloWorld = QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("SomeScope", "Hello world");
```

*Later...*

```
return qApp->translate("SomeScope", kHelloWorld);
```

This is still in your source code somewhere, but it is at least one step removed. You could theoretically have the `QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP` stuff in an entirely different Qt project, but then you'd need *some* way in your real project to know what you are supposed to translate. (You still need the char* constants *somewhere*.)

What are you trying to accomplish exactly by not having the English text in the source? That might help people provide more appropriate answers.

**EDIT**

*Based on your comment below about intended usage*

OK, then this is precisely what the normal Qt translation process does. Running `lupdate` creates those XML files (they have a .ts extension). They can be opened by translators in the very-easy-to-use Qt Linguist. They are translated, then sent back to you (the programmer), where you run `lrelease` on them to create the binary translation files you will ship with the app. The translations are resolved *at runtime*, so there is no need to recompile.

If you wanted to enable a user to do this, you would:

- Ship your application with an empty (untranslated) `.ts` file and the `lrelease` program.
- Provide instructions on how to use Qt Linguist to translate. (They could use a text editor and modify the Xml directly, but it's a lot easier with Linguist.)
- Explain how to run `lrelease` and where to drop the binary translation files so that your application pulls them in.

On this last step, you could theoretically provide a nice wizard-like app that hides the implementation details.

Comment: My target is that someone without source code access could adjust texts (in all languages), without the need of some processes to run or recalculate something. Imagine 5 languages (incl. the "source language") would result in 5 identically formated, human readable files (e.g. xml). What I get from QT is hundreds of source files with text plus some processed xml files for the other 4 languages.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from including your default language as another translation language--Qt will override the source code values with the translated values if it finds a match.

Comment: In fact, you *have* to include translation files for your default language (say, English) if you want to use things like plural forms, etc. We're doing this on our projects.